# Error using reflection, when trying to get the type

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to use reflection.

Here is my function using reflection:

`name = "IfcPolyLoop"`
`polyLoopLine="#99= IFCPOLYLOOP((#101,#103,#105,#107));"`

```
    private void convertFirstIfcPolyLoop(string typeName,string polyLoopLine)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, polyLoopLine, this.listDictionaries);
        this.AddOrError((IfcElement)instance);
    }
```

What I want to do is something equivalent to that :

```
private void convertFirstIfcPolyLoop(string polyLoopLine)
{
    IfcPolyLoop newElt = new IfcPolyLoop(polyLoopLine, this.listDictionaries)
}
```

But I want to use reflection.

But when I do `var type = Type.GetType(typeName);`, type is still set to null, and I think I am supposed to obtain `IfcPolyLoop`

Comment: Please create a [mre]. All this grouping and looping and explaining what your variables contain is irrelevant. Create from scratch, apart from the classes you're trying to instantiate, the like 5 lines of code that reproduce the issue, give us something to work with. My guess and hint would be that type names are case sensitive.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, sorry, will make a minimal function instead, just one minute

Comment: Contains `name` the assembly qualified name? Does the received type having a ctor with the correct parameter types of `line` and `ListDictionaries`?

Comment: Pay utmost attention to the reference API documentation for Type.GetType(string), particularly what it says about the string parameter it expects.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok, I guess it's fine so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the classes are in the same namespaces, you need to provide the class name along with the namespace.

So for example you need to pass `YourNamespace.YourClassName` as the string value to the `Type.GetType` method.

In my case, it worked when passing as "ConsoleApp1.Program2" for the class `Program2` in `ConsoleApp1` namespace.

Comment: yes, in fact it seems that solved my problem